# What does Krishna mean when he says falsehood may be uttered on the occasion of enjoying a woman?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dharma

From [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08069.htm)

> "Listen to it, O Dhananjaya! One who speaks truth is righteous. There
>   is nothing higher than truth. Behold, however, truth as practised is
>   exceedingly difficult to be understood as regards its essential
>   attributes. Truth may be unutterable, and even falsehood may be
>   utterable where falsehood would become truth and truth would become
>   falsehood. In a situation of peril to life and in marriage, falsehood
>   becomes utterable. In a situation involving the loss of one's entire
>   property, falsehood becomes utterable. **On an occasion of marriage, or
>   of enjoying a woman, or when life is in danger, or when one's entire
>   property is about to be taken away, or for the sake of a Brahmana,
>   falsehood may be uttered.** These five kinds of falsehood have been
>   declared to be sinless. On these occasions falsehood would become
>   truth and truth would become falsehood. He is a fool that practises
>   truth without knowing the difference between truth and falsehood. One
>   is said to be conversant with morality when one is able to distinguish
>   between truth and falsehood. "

Does he mean whispering sweet nothings to your wife or lying to seduce a woman who is not your wife?

Comment: Astounding! Can you put Sanskrit verses also if possible. :O

Comment: Include this in details - "Is there any explanation of his words we somewhere found in the Mahabharata or other scriptures?", Otherwise it might look like opinion based.

Comment: @iammilind Your answer & explanation is good but it doesn't answer this question at all. You just quoted the same quote at the last.

Comment: @Rajas, I may not be completely answering that part. However the Qn does ask about this Qn. If either of the criteria are met then it's a possible duplicate. Intention is to combine the answers of both the Qn-s in single thread for the good of future visitors.

Comment: This is not found in [Sanskrit](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs08049.htm) on same website neither in critical edition.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani are you sure? So this is not true?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 7):

Kṛṣṇa probably means it in the following sense.

> [Manusmṛti 8.112](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201022.html)
>
> कामिनीषु विवाहेषु गवां भक्ष्ये तथेन्धने । 
>   ब्राह्मणाभ्युपपत्तौ च शपथे नास्ति पातकम् ॥ ११२ ॥
>
> kāminīṣu vivāheṣu gavāṃ bhakṣye tathendhane |
>  
>   brāhmaṇābhyupapattau ca śapathe nāsti pātakam || 112 ||
>
> **There is no serious offence in swearing to women**, or in connection with marriages, fodder for cows, or fuel, or for the sake of a Brāhmaṇa.—(112)
>
> ---
>
> **Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya)**:
>
> ‘Kāminīṣu’—‘Kāma’ is a particular form of pleasure caused through the tactile organ; and those who are productive of such pleasure are called ‘Kāminī,’—which is a terra that stands for wife, courtesans and so forth. To these if one swears, for the fulfilment of his desire—**in such words as ‘I do not love any other woman, thou art the queen of my heart,’ etc.,—there is nothing wrong in this**; though, if after meeting the women, and on being asked by her to give a certain thing, he swears falsely that he would give it to her,—then this is certainly wrong.
>
> ...
>
> ---
>
> **Explanatory notes by Ganganath Jha**
>
> This verse is quoted in Smṛtitattva (II, p. 229), which adds the following notes:—‘Kāminīṣu,’ **when conversing with a woman in secret one may swear falsely for the purpose of satisfying her**;—similarly for the purpose of bringing about a marriage, for obtaining food for cows, for obtaining fuel necessary for offerings, and for saving a Brāhmaṇa;—and in Vyavahāra-Bālambhaṭṭī (p. 406).

Comment: Basically to satisfy a women? Or lessen her anger?

Comment: This sounds so sexist!

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury thankfully not found in critical edition of Mahabharata.

Comment: @SuryaKanta, once you are married then you will find this same approach as a 'practice' instead of 'sexist'. :-) From my personal experience, a marriage works only after a 'man' transforms to 'yes man'. Most of the authors in this site are bachelors, hence they speak of 'ideals'; but married man eventualy become 'practical'.

Comment: @iammilind I don't want to marry lol

Comment: @AnubhavJha, yeah, they should write an edition of mahabharata with truth edited out to make sure the people don't get offended.

Comment: @ram No changing scriptures is bad, but this isn't sexist. In this case, he's just saying lying for fun in a case to not anger or annoy a woman is fine. Also, this is just in regards to dramatic or over-theatrical sentences stated by a man during his case of love.