# Which are the 18 Smritis? In which Hindu text are they listed?

Tags: smriti

It is often said that there are 18 smritis. But despite searching for a long time I have not come across a single Hindu text that lists 18 smritis.

The [Yajnavalkha smriti](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Asiatic_Journal_and_Monthly_Register_for/qxEoAAAAYAAJ?hl=en) lists 20 smritis which I have listed below (although the number is sometimes reduced to 19 by considering the Likhita and Sankha smritis as one since the authors were brothers).

> Manu, Atri, Vishnu, Harita, Yajnavalkya, Usana, Angira, Yama,
> Apastamba, Samvarta, Katyayana, Brihaspati, Parashara, Vyasa, Sankha,
> Likhita, Daksha, Gautama, Satatapa and Vashishta.

The [Parashara Smriti](https://archive.org/details/ParasharaSmriti) also lists 20 smritis although it replaces Yama, Brihaspati and Vyasa with Kashyapa, Gargya and Pracheta. And the [Padma Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31493/how-many-available-smriti-are-there-in-total) lists 36 smritis; its list is similar to the one used by Yajnavalkha but it omits Atri and adds the following 17 new smritis

> Marichi, Pulastya, Pracheta, Bhrigu, Narada, Kashyapa, Vishvamitra,
> Devala, Rishyasringa, Gargya, Baudhayana, Paithinashi, Javali,
> Samantu, Paraskara, Lokaksh and Kuthumi

The only [source](https://www.sivanandaonline.org//?cmd=displaysection&section_id=572#:%7E:text=There%20are%20eighteen%20main%20Smritis,%2C%20Usana%2C%20Atri%20and%20Saunaka.) I know which lists 18 smritis is the Divine Life Society of Swami Sivananda. But Sivananda does not mention his source nor did he belong to a well recognised monk order like the one at Sringeri Sarada Peetham or Kanchi Kamakshi Peetham so I don't think his list can be taken with a massive grain of salt.

Comment: Related or Duplicate -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31493/4732

Comment: I read your answer. You said the Yajnavalkha smriti lists 18 smritis but if you count all the smritis you gave it's actually 20, not 18.  Similarly the Parashara smriti also lists 20 smritis and the Padma Purana lists 36.

Comment: If the scriptures say that there are 19 Smritis or 20 then that is the answer. There is no need to move ahead with the assumption that there are 18 if scriptural evidence says otherwise.